# ajax working when function is on child theme but not in plugin page

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax which passes some jQuery variables to PHP function. My function was supposed to be in a class file. But ajax won't work and shows **bad request**. But if i place php function in my child theme, it works perfectly.

Here is my jQuery AJAX

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: ajaxurl,                        
      data: {
      action: 'thwec_get_element_block_data',
      block_element_list: block_element_list
    },
     success:function(data){
      alert('success');
      console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(){
      alert('error');
     }
    });
```

And my PHP function.

```
public function __construct() {
    add_action('wp_ajax_thwec_get_element_block_data',array($this,'get_element_block_data')); 

    // $this->get_element_block_data();
    // $this->init_constants();
}

public function get_element_block_data(){
    var_dump("hello");
    exit();
}
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in this line     add_action('wp_ajax_thwec_get_element_block_data',array($this,'get_element_block_data'); there should be an extra brace

Comment: updated . But same issue remains . @VidyaL

Comment: need also wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)

Comment: tried. no use @ravipatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Oren Havshush** said class file was included and the instance of the class was written but the instance of the class was not called. Thank you all for your time

Answer (score 1):

is your plugin activated?

once you put ajax action in plugin or in functions.php it is working the same way, as long as the plugin is activated
the only different is that in your plugin it is a class and you called it correctly.

Comment: plugin is active

Comment: are you logged in ?

Comment: just to be clear, the class is in a plugin, the plugin is activated and you are logged in user ? are you sure you have the class init  ? can you try to add die() in the constructor and see that it is being called ?

Comment: Yes. Its a part of plugin development. My whole work is around a plugin. Ajax code and php function is in plugin

Comment: You were right .init class was defined but  was not being called.